# Laravel How to loop through arrays and get values by key

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In my `laravel`-application I have two arrays, one called "headers" and one called "rows" and I only want the data from the "row" array which is based on the key from the "headers" array.

So here are my arrays:

```
  "rows" => array:2 [
     0 => array:6 [
        "Company name" => "Universal"
        "Address" => "Some address"
        "Zipcode" => 12122
        "City" => "Some city"
        "Phonenumber" => 12345678
        "Email" => "mail@mail.com"
     ],
     1 => array:6 [
        "Company name" => "Warner Bros."
        "Address" => "another address"
        "Zipcode" => 12122
        "City" => "city abc"
        "Phonenumber" => 12345678
        "Email" => "mail2@mail.com"
     ]

  ],
  "headers" => array:4 [
     0 => array:2 [
       "name" => "Company name"
       "data" => array:1 [
          "value" => "company_name"
       ]
     ],
     1 => array:2 [
      "name" => "Adresse"
      "data" => array:1 [
         "value" => "address"
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

So far so good, now I only want the data from the "rows"-array which is selected from the "headers" array, so that I can display them like this in my frontend:

```
Company name    |    Address
----------------------------------
Universal       |    Some address
Warner Bros.    |    Another address
```

So, how can I store them in the database? My Model structure is this:

```
Entry::create([
    'company_name' => request()->company_name ?? null,
    'address' => request()->address ?? null,
    'zipcode' => request()->zipcode ?? null,
    'city' => request()->city ?? null,
    'number' => request()->number ?? null,
    'email' => request()->email ?? null
]);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: how can you store what in the database?

Comment: hi friend you as per the question you want to store only the name and address in the store above 2 companies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi friend loop through the companies array first, and dynamically create a array and pass it to the model as below

```
$data = $request->rows;
$columns = $request->headers;

foreach($data as $item){

  $array_of_items = [] 
  
  foreach($columns as $column){
     
     $column_name = $column['name']; //should return "Company Name"      

     if($item[$column_name]){ // means has the value
       $column_code = $column['data']['value'] //should return "company_name" in first loop and so on, if not cannot carry on
       $array_of_items[$column_code] = $item[$column_name];
     }
     
  }

  if(!empty($array_of_items)){
     Entry::create($array_of_items);
  }


}
```

If anything in doubt feel free to comment, thank you have a nice day.

Comment: Hmm but you changed the array from "Company name" to "company_name" - In this case I can't do that but you gave me an idea :-)

Comment: You want "Company Name" as it is? ok let me edit the answer then

Comment: @ST80 Updated the code Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to for loop the `row` and create a record for each entry.

```php
foreach(request()->input('row') as $entry){
    Entry::create([
        'company_name' => $entry['Company name'] ?? null,
        'address'      => $entry['Address'] ?? null,
        'zipcode'      => $entry['Zipcode'] ?? null,
        'city'         => $entry['City'] ?? null,
        'number'       => $entry['Phonenumber'] ?? null,
        'email'        => $entry['Email'] ?? null
    ]);
}
```